# print issue in safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used below css for select tag.

```
select {  vertical-align:middle; float:left; border:1px solid #cccccc; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding:2px; font-size:14px; height:35px ;}

Here is the HTML version:

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If I see the print preview, it is not good on safari browser. Please help us.

Comment: What's the problem? A screen shot might help you get some more advice. I'm guessing it's the background color?

Comment: Background color doesn't display in print preview.

Comment: This is by design and applies to many browsers. You cannot control it. Look for other alternatives to background-color

Comment: If I remove background-color and border-color, the default style displays correct in print preview.

Comment: As DaveHogan says: Most browsers don't print background colors/images. That default color is printed is probably a quirk/bug. Most browsers however do have an option to manually turn background printing back on, but there is nothing you can do about it in CSS.

Comment: You need to review the settings of your browser print. It is likely not CSS related.

Answer (score 0):

This article agrees with above replies, but suggests using different border options for different elements. Might be a possible next solution to check out.

http://css-tricks.com/dont-rely-on-background-colors-printing/

Answer (score 0):

This css solved the issue.

```
select {  vertical-align:middle; float:left; border:1px solid #cccccc; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding:2px; font-size:14px; height:35px;  -webkit-appearance:none;}
```